# How do you determine the volume of a balloon so that it takes off?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-statics

Could someone explain me the solution please? I am stuck in this exercise.

Question:

> A balloon has the mass m = 10 g and is inflated with helium so that the final pressure is p = 1.5 bar. How large must the volume of the balloon be so that it lifts off the ground? The density of helium on the earth's surface and at normal temperature is $Q_{Helium}$ = 0.178 $\frac{kg}{m^3}$.

Solution:

Buoyancy force F = $p_0$Vg =($M_b$+$M_{He}$)g

$$\rightarrow V = \frac{mB}{Q_0Q_{\mathrm{He}}(1.5\mathrm{bar})} = 1.02\cdot10^{-2}\mathrm{m}^3$$ with $$\frac{p_1}{p_0} = \frac{Q_1}{Q_0}\rightarrow Q_{\mathrm{He}}(1.5\mathrm{bar}) = Q_{\mathrm{He}}(1.0\mathrm{bar})\cdot1.5$$

Comment: What do you use for the density of the surrounding air?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: i use 1.24 for the surrounding air

Answer (score 1):

Overall density is the key. When is the total density of balloon+helium less than or equal to air the balloon floats.

Helium is less dens than air so always floats. The flattened balloon is heavier so always sinks. But if you fill the balloon, you are adding more helium (which always floats on its own so cannot make the assembly sink) while the amount of balloon stays the same, but volume is always increasing. Therefore overall density just keeps decreasing asymptotically towards the density of helium, which we know floats.